# Setting Drupal's Home URL and Navigation Menu URLs for Virtual Host on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, drupal

I've installed Apache2 and Drupal6 and necessary dependencies on Ubuntu 10.10 (using `apt-get install drupal6`). When I initially set up Drupal, I accessed it through a URL like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/drupal6/node
```

I subsequently set up the virtual host in Apache, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/drupal6
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
</VirtualHost>
```

So now I can get to all my Drupal stuff with this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/node
```

This is all well and good.  However, the URLs for the home link in the upper left and the URLs in the Drupal navigation menu still have the `/drupal6/` part in them.  So, for example, if I click the Administer link, it goes to `http://mydomain.com/drupal6/admin`, and then all other URLs are relative to that.  (Note: `http://mydomain.com/admin` works just fine too.)

How can I get rid of that `/drupal6/` part in the URLs?  I can't find anything in `settings.php` or in the admin screens to change it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out about 30 seconds after posting the question (after an hour of hair-pulling before posting the question).

In `/usr/share/drupal6/.htaccess`, comment out this line:

```
RewriteBase /drupal6
```

and uncomment out this line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

(I missed this because the command `grep drupal6 *` skips `.htaccess`.  Who was the genius who came up with "hidden" files?)

Comment: With command line expansion, * will only expand to *. and not .* -- this is a function of the shell and not really a deficiency in grep.